# How to print a unicode string properly in Azure DevOps using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, unicode

I want to log the stdout to the logging of an Azure DevOps task.

This is a part of my powershell script:

```
    $pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    $pinfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe"
    $pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
    $pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
    $pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
    $pinfo.Arguments = "/i `"<<my-msi-file>>`" REBOOT=ReallySuppress /L*v+ $logFile /qn"
    $p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $p.StartInfo = $pinfo
    $p.Start() | Out-Null
    $p.WaitForExit()
    $stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    Write-Host "stdout: $stdout"
```

I do get the output, but it is displayed wrong. I am not able to copy and paste it properly, but this is what it more or less looks like (I don't know the exact character, it might be null-charaters as well):

> Example text

How can I display the text like "Example text"?

**EDIT:**
To get an error text on stdout, just fill in for `<<my-msi-file>>` a nonexistent filename, e.g. `c:\dev\null\nofile.msi`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share `$stdout | Format-Hex -Encoding  UTF8` as well as `$stdout | Format-Hex -Encoding Unicode`…

Comment: `install-package .\file.msi`

Comment: @JosefZ I explained a little bit more how to get text on stdout. But maybe your comment is the answer I am looking for. Within 12 hours I will try the `Format-Hex` command and let you know if that works.

Comment: @JosefZ Here the result: 
`2023-08-03T12:44:28.9553160Z stdout: 00000000   54 00 68 00 69 00 73 00 20 00 69 00 6E 00 73 00  T.h.i.s. .i.n.s.
2023-08-03T12:44:28.9657942Z 00000010   74 00 61 00 6C 00 6C 00 61 00 74 00 69 00 6F 00  t.a.l.l.a.t.i.o.`
As I already suspected, they are all null-characters in between.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JosefZ I was put in the right direction.
The output of msiexec.exe is apparently in unicode.

I added two lines to my script and now the output is shown correct:

```
$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$pinfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe"
$pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
$pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
###################################################################
$pinfo.StandardOutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::unicode
$pinfo.StandardErrorEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::unicode
###################################################################
$pinfo.Arguments = "/i `"<<my-msi-file>>`" REBOOT=ReallySuppress /L*v+ $logFile /qn"
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo
$p.Start() | Out-Null
$p.WaitForExit()
$stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
Write-Host "stdout: $stdout"
```